# Three inequalities with a common constraint

Tags: inequality

A question struck me today and to be able to answer it I wrote it down as a mathematical expression and have been able to simplify the question to the following:

Given $$x > 1,y > 1,z > 1$$ $$x+y+z > S$$ what is the smallest $S$ that guarantees

$$Ax > A+B+C$$
$$By > A+B+C$$
$$Cz > A+B+C$$

if $A,B,C$ are chosen correctly after $x,y,z$ become known, where $A,B,C$ are positive numbers?

I do not even know *if* there exists a value of $S$ that satisfies this. Furthermore, after I find out the value of $S$, how would I go about choosing the numbers $A, B$, and $C$? I would guess that by finding $S$, you would also find out how to choose the numbers, but perhaps that is not the case.

Do not refrain from answering even if you do not have a complete answer. Partial answers are certainly not unwanted.

Comment: Are $A,B,C,x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}$ or integers?

Comment: They are not integers, but I am certain that only their relationship matters. You could make them all integers if you wanted by multiply them all by the same number.

Comment: The relationship of A, B, and C I mean. x, y, and z are not integers in general. The LHS of the inequality is a continuous function as far as I can imagine.

Comment: I made a mistake in the original version of the question. It has been edited now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No value of $S$ guarantees that this is possible.

Note that choosing positive $A,B,C$ is equivalent to choosing positive $\lambda,\mu,\nu$ such that $\lambda+\mu+\nu=1$ and $\lambda x>1,\mu y>1,\nu z>1$. [Just divide the inequalities by $A+B+C$ to see this.]

Now suppose that $x>S,y=z=1.5$. Then we certainly have $x+y+z>S$. But to ensure that $\mu y>1$ and $\nu z>1$, we need $$\mu>\frac{2}{3},\nu>\frac{2}{3},\mu+\nu<1$$ which is impossible.

Comment: It seems you replaced *A/(A+B+C)* with *λ*, etc. Where do you get $λ+μ+ν=1$?

Comment: $\frac{A}{A+B+C}+\frac{B}{A+B+C}+\frac{C}{A+B+C}=1$

Comment: Nice work. Thanks.